# Catching data in controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I have a question about javascript and cakephp, I need to send data via Post and recive it in the other side (the controller) and make the normal process that I already have. But I don't know how can I catch the data. I'm working with Ajax

```js
function editFun(clicked_id){
    var id = clicked_id;
    $("#Content").empty();
    $('#Content').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Posts/edit',
        data: (id)
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#Content').html(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        $('#Content').html(data);
    });
}
```

```html
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
     throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
     throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
     $this->Post->id = $id;
     if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
      return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
     }
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
    }
    if (!$this->request->data) {
     $this->request->data = $post;
    }
   }
```

Comment: When calling via Ajax, the data doesn't get sent the normal way.  I don't quite remember which variable you can expect to find the data in, so check `$this->request` and `$this->params->query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you should send your id in URL. So even GET method is enough, because you controller receive `$id` param from URL.

So all what you need to change are post arguments:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Posts/edit/' + id
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the answer!!